# how to fixed (can't not pip install packages)

Tags: python, pycharm

```
Z:\code\fblogin>pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Using cached selenium-4.17.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.26 in ...
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      _configtest.c
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-313
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\backend_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\cffi_opcode.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\commontypes.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\cparser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\error.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\ffiplatform.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\lock.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\model.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\pkgconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\recompiler.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\setuptools_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\vengine_cpy.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\vengine_gen.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\verifier.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\_imp_emulation.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\_shimmed_dist_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\_cffi_include.h -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\parse_c_type.h -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\_embedding.h -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      copying src\cffi\_cffi_errors.h -> build\lib.win32-cpython-313\cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-313
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src\c
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src\c\libffi_x86_x64
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -Isrc/c/libffi_x86_x64
 -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\include -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Bui
ldTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Wi
ndows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/c/_cffi_backend.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/_cffi_backend.obj
      _cffi_backend.c
      src/c/_cffi_backend.c(4521): warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types - from 'PyUnicodeObject *' to 'PyObject *'
      src/c/_cffi_backend.c(4532): warning C4996: 'Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding': deprecated in 3.12
      src/c/_cffi_backend.c(6121): warning C4013: '_PyErr_WriteUnraisableMsg' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -Isrc/c/libffi_x86_x64
 -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\include -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Bui
ldTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Wi
ndows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/c/libffi_x86_x64\ffi.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\ffi.obj
      ffi.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -Isrc/c/libffi_x86_x64
 -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\include -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Bui
ldTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Wi
ndows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/c/libffi_x86_x64\prep_cif.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\prep_cif.obj
      prep_cif.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -Isrc/c/libffi_x86_x64
 -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\include -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Bui
ldTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Wi
ndows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/c/libffi_x86_x64\types.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\types.obj
      types.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -Isrc/c/libffi_x86_x64
 -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\include -IC:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Bui
ldTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\
2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Wi
ndows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/c/libffi_x86_x64\win32.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\win32.obj
      win32.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /
LIBPATH:C:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313-32 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\letru\AppData\Local\Programs\Pyth
on\Python313-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86" "/
LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit__cffi_backend build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/_cffi_backend.obj build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Re
lease\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\ffi.obj build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\prep_cif.obj build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\types.obj build\temp.win3
2-cpython-313\Release\src/c/libffi_x86_x64\win32.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-cpython-313\_cffi_backend.cp313-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c\_cffi_backend.cp313-wi
n32.lib
         Creating library build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c\_cffi_backend.cp313-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-cpython-313\Release\src/c\_cffi_backend.cp313-win32.exp
      _cffi_backend.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __PyErr_WriteUnraisableMsg
      build\lib.win32-cpython-313\_cffi_backend.cp313-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
Failed to build cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cffi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Can you share your env? A good starting point is your SO, Python version, the output of pip list env, etc :)

Comment: `creating build\lib.win32-cpython-313` Are you using 3.13 ? It tries to build the lib from source, which fails. Try using a supported python version: "CFFI is tested with CPython 3.8-3.12."

Answer (score 0):

A few recommendations:

### 1. Upgrade Pip and Setuptools:

Sometimes can resolve build issues. Run the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

### 2. Sometimes, the absence of OpenSSL can cause build issues.

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

### 3. Install cffi Directly:

Try installing the cffi package directly before attempting to install selenium. It is a C main dependency that usually raises issues with selenium.

```
pip install cffi
```

### 4. Review the supported python versions with selenium

Ensure that you are using a compatible version of Python for the packages you are installing.